# Error sending data to a HTTPS server with as3httpclientlib

Tags: actionscript-3, https, client-server

I'm trying to send some data from flash to a server. I was doing it with a test server and everything was ok. But when I change to test it into a real server it send me an error: " got Alert! Type=22" So I searched about it and I discover that its because the real server runs on HTTPS and the test runs on HTTP. So, reading the documentation of the as3httpclienlib library that I am using, I found that there is a bug with some HTTPS servers and cause some errors and don't leave flash send more than 40kb of data, so that throws the error Type 22 -> Record overflow

This only happens with TLS Sockets so I think that the solution is change the TLSSocket to a SSLSocket.

This is the code that I use to send the data to the server:

```
var client:HttpClient = new HttpClient();
var uri:URI = new URI("http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.cgi");
var variables:Array = [{name:"fname", value:"FirstName1"}, {name:"lname", value: "LastName1"}];

client.listener.onData = function(event:HttpDataEvent):void {
  // Notified with response content in event.bytes as it streams in
};

client.listener.onComplete = function(event:HttpResponseEvent):void {
  // Notified when complete (after status and data)
};

client.postFormData(uri, variables);
```

How can I change this sockets?

Does anyone have an example?

Is this the solution of the problem?

Comment: There isn't easy way to change socket from _TLSSocket_ to _SecureSocket_ in _as3httpclientlib_. Error 22 in _TLSSocket_ can be due to errors in parsing server certificate. Try this patched library version https://github.com/fsbmain/as3public

Comment: Thank you fsbmain, I tried the patched version of AS3Crypto library that you post and now the image is loaded on the server, but the connection is closed before the data is fully loaded so if you decoded the image manually, it is cropped, and the other data going after the base 64 string variable is not loaded because the connection is closed. I think the problem of the amount of data continues and this pach only solves the problem with the HTTPS connection.

Have anyone an idea how to solve this? Is there another library to do the same but without these problems?

Thanks!

Comment: But why you don't want to use native as3 _URLLoader_? I haven't all this issues with TLS/SSL.

Comment: Because I have to make a connection to a REST server and I have to send the variables as shown in the code that I have as an example. I am sending the variables to an API and this is the way that it should be sent.

Comment: Is that you need _PULL_ and _PUT_ requests? There is a common practice to use an additional param (for instance _reqType=put_) for the request type for the as3 client in _REST_ services, because of using _as3httpclient_ have other lack, for example it required socket policy server. As for the connection, I havn't other ideas why it closed and on which side (client or server). I can only advice you to use only TLS and not use SSL in _TLSSocket_, because I have bugs with _SSL_ in it.